# The discriminant of (1,x,x^2) in a cubic field.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, determinant, extension-field

Let $K$ be a cubic field such that $K=\mathbb Q[x]$ with $x^3=2$.

The discriminant of $\{1,x,x^2\}$ is supposed to be $\begin{vmatrix} 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 6 \\ 0 & 6 & 0\end{vmatrix}$, but when computing it with traces ($D(1,x,x^2)=\det(\text{Tr}_{K/ \mathbb Q}(x^ix^j)), i,j \in \{0,1,2\}$) I get $\begin{vmatrix} 3 & 3x & 3x^2 \\ 3x & 3x^2 & 6 \\ 3x^2 & 6 & 6x\end{vmatrix}$. What am I doing wrong?

(I have little experience with computing discriminants so far)

Comment: The discriminant of what kind of object are you trying to compute? (a polynomial, an algebraic number field, ...?)

Comment: The discriminant of the set $(1,x,x^2)$, where $x^3=2$.

Comment: I have no idea what the discriminant of a set is, nor does the notation $(1,x,x^2)$ look like a set

Comment: You're right about the notation, I will edit it. The discriminant of a set        $\{x_1, \dots x_n\} \in K^n$ is $\det( \text{Tr}_{K / \mathbb Q} (x_ix_j))$

Comment: The trace of $\root3\of2$ is zero. How are you getting $3\root3\of2$ instead?

Comment: Can you explain why it is zero? I think I got confused.

Comment: The trace is the sum of the conjugates. The conjugates are the zeros of the minimal polynomial. The minimal polynomial for $\root3\of2$ is $x^3-2$. The zeros of this polynomial add up to zero.

Comment: Good. Let me suggest you write up what you now know, and post it as an answer.